# Android Custom Keyboard like Pie Control

Tags: java, android

I want to develop custom keyboard like Pie Control, iOS' AssistiveTouch, the things I want to say **floating and round shaped keyboard.** [Here's mock-up written in JavaScript.](https://github.com/Ziggomatic/circlekey) and now I'm edit some xml in sdk softkeyboard sample. but this input method is occupying bottom area with gray screen. I want remove and transparent this.

1. Can I create based with sdk sample?
2. If develop without sdk, what class do I need to use?

Thanks.

Sorry for the terrible image below!

[image]

Comment: First try something yourself, and then post your questions.

Comment: sorry for noob quesiton, I even don't know what I don't know. I found some [keyboard app that floating.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.knobkeyboard.keyboard) what it uses class? and in sdk/layout/input.xml, `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` looks locks keyboard at bottom, but nothing changed even "false"

Comment: by asking these kind of questions, you may get banned from asking questions.